# Best practice of the spring application call async request

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, call

I use `Spring framework` in `web service`, I need to call a 3rd async rest service such as create `VM`.

When I call the create `VM` service, It return me a `vm_id`. The `VM` is created in background.

I save the `vm_id` in database, and start a timer to check the `VM` status by the `vm_id` and update the status to my database.

Because my application is a distributed service, it may contain more than one node.

**Every node has it's own timers and it's corresponding `vm_ids` to check their status.**

If one node is fail, how other node know this and start a new timer for the `vm_ids` which the failed node have processed?

Is the `scheduler` in spring OK for this?